# Is there any way to overwrite the cap deploy:setup task?

Tags: php, ruby, symfony1, capistrano, capifony

Where can I find the capifony/capistrano tasks in order to overwrite them.

I want when I run cap deploy:setup to modify it to add an extra symlink to accomodate my server structure. Is that possible? Or at least to write a new task to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of cap tasks :
http://capitate.rubyforge.org/recipes/deploy.html

To override tasks do something like that :

```
 namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart do ; end
  task :update_code do ; end #override this task to prevent capistrano to upload on servers
  task :symlink do ; end #don't create the current symlink to the last release
 end
```

Comment: Where is the correct place to override tasks?  lib/capistrano/tasks/task_name.cap or Capfile or config/deploy.rb?